# Can ARToolkit be used with Unity on the Android platform?

Tags: android, unity

Does anyone know if ARToolkit can be integrated with Unity and work on Android phones? It would be helpful if you could share any examples or resources.

Comment: Please be more specific.

Answer (score 2):

ARToolkit itself supports the Android platform. On the Unity forums, you can find a [beta for the UnityAR project](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/30817-UnityAR-ARToolkit-Interface), which provides ARToolkit integration with Unity.

Even if the UnityAR project does not meet your needs, you could develop your own integration. It is certainly possible.